# How to implement redis streams with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, redis

I am going to implement a Redis stream to serve has a message queue / message broker and I was asking myself about the structure of the NodeJs code that will serve that purpose.
I mean, knowing that the objective is to continue to consume messages over and over again I do not see a clean way to do this other than :

```
while(true){
    >get a message from stream with a blocker XREADGROUP BLOCK ...
    >do some magic
    >acknowledge magic is done XACK ...
}
```

Because I think any recursive function will create more and more instances of the running function and a pretty massive memory / computational leak.

Any other ideas ? Am I missing something ?

(Of course I intend to do it in a NodeJs cluster and I already made a boilerplate code to manage consumers etc so I'm just asking about the structure of workers' code here)

Comment: This is the way. Alternatively, you could use xgroupread and relay messages asynchronously to a `steam.Readable` and have a separate stream.Writable consume and ack messages. This may yield a higher throughput of messages at the cost of increased processing in Redis, as all messages must be ack-ed.

Comment: I edited the question and changed XREAD to XREADGROUP because I already wanted to use consumer groups and did not remember that wasn't possible with XREAD.
Question remains, why such a way to handle redis streams with stream.Writable etc would yield higher throughput (because we still need to get data from redis stream, process etc)(that seams like an increased CPU consumption to me, just adding a kinda middleware process) and how the code could be structured : specialised workers or every worker writing and reading to the nodejs stream ?

Comment: There's always a tradeoff between throughput and load. Buffering messages in a readable (i.e., fetching them from a Redis stream using IO and storing them in memory) will sidestep the expected lag caused by waiting for the IO controller to fetch more data. This does not entail a CPU load increase as the CPU would have processed these messages anyway. However, messages may no longer be processed in a FIFO manner as different workers consuming the same stream may yield different burn rates. Also, workers should be scaled horizontally by starting multiple nodejs processes (or Kubernetes pods).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'm not sure that this implementation is worth the time cost (of me understanding and coding this thing), so I'm going with the easy solution for now but be sure I'm going to dig deeper when the time will come. Thanks !